# How to make Pydantic recognize 'type' field as a discriminator in a LegacyOperationRepresentationType?

Tags: python, validation, pydantic

I have problem with discriminator in pydantic.

```
exec(
        f"""
class LegacyOperation{cls_name}(NamedTuple):
    type: Literal["{cls.get_name()}"]  # noqa: A003
    value: {cls_name}
    """
```

I have model like this, and the it is a union of few classes:

```
LegacyOperationRepresentationUnionType = Union[tuple(__create_legacy_representation(arg) for arg in get_args(LegacyOperationType))]
```

And finally:

```
LegacyOperationRepresentationType = Annotated[LegacyOperationRepresentationUnionType, Field(discriminator="type")]
```

But pydantic don't see type field as discriminator. I think it would be a good way to put index into discriminator but it is impossible.

I tried to put name of NamedTuple into discriminator but it doesn't works.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I suggest you read the articles on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then use the _Edit_ function to modify your question accordingly.

The practice of boiling the code down to the bare minimum needed to capture the essence of the problem not only motivates others to actually try and help you but more often than not gives you a deeper understanding to solve the problem yourself.